# Valid name for control

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm currently working with DevExpress Xtrareports, and I'm having problems setting the name of reports (which will be displayed in the print queue)

I'm setting the .Name property on an instance of XtraReport I created in code to a value from a database field. For some values this throws exceptions.

The problem seems to be that XtraReport inherits the name property from XRControl which is the base class for a visual control.

So I can only set the name to a value that's valid as a name for a visual control in winforms.

I've searched google, and it's surprisingly hard to find a clear list of what the rules are for a valid control name in windows forms.

I know it can't begin with a number, or contains dots or hyphens ('-').

Does anyone know the complete rules, or where I can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control name should be a valid identifier, something you could use to name a variable. This depends on your .net language of choice. For C# 4.0 the valid identifiers are described in part 2.4.2 of the language specification ([download from microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029))

To paraphrase: start with **letter** or **underscore**, followed by:

**letter-character:**
A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl
A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl

**combining-character:**
A Unicode character of classes Mn or Mc
A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of classes Mn or Mc

**decimal-digit-character:**
A Unicode character of the class Nd
A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of the class Nd

**connecting-character:**
A Unicode character of the class Pc
A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of the class Pc

**formatting-character:**
A Unicode character of the class Cf
A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of the class Cf

A short description of the unicode character classes can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/XML/0060__XML-Schema/Unicodecharacterclasses.htm)